# WooCommerce API Add Role to Customer

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to figure out how to add a role to a customer via the WooCommerce REST API.

What I thought would be correct of simply adding "role":"test_role" doesnt appear to work as the docs are indicating its read only.

Im quite new to WooCommerce, and would have thought simply adding a role to user wouldnt be a difficult task.

Is there a way to extend the API to make this writable? or is it even possible to add a role to a customer?